# Error while performing angular & node migration

Tags: node.js, angular, migration, primeng

Performing migration from Angular 6 to 7 and Node 8 to 10 simultaneously.
Have used PrimeNg widgets throughout the application. But an error is popped up only in the TreeTable widget (on selecting a node).

[image: Error Image]

This might be a general issue.

Comment: This is a known issue and it has been raised. Please find the link for the same https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7068